# Selecting min count('x') by year

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a table that displays the song(s) with the minimum number of plays by year.

For instance if Song1 and Song2 both only had 1 play and Song3 had 2 plays in 2018 and Song1 had 1 play in 2017 and Song2 had 2 plays in 2017, I want a table that would return 3 rows:

Song1 - 2018 - 1 play

Song2 - 2018 - 1 play

Song1 - 2017 - 1 play

Is there a way to display the songs where min(count('x')) = count('x').
I'm sure that isn't the proper syntax but it's essentially what I'm trying to find.

```
SELECT * FROM music 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT extract(year from date) AS yr, song_code, COUNT('x') 
FROM singles NATURAL JOIN plays 
GROUP BY extract(year from date), song_code
ORDER BY yr desc, COUNT('x') desc);
```

Currently I have the songs grouped by number of plays a year, but I'm not sure how to only show those that have played the minimum amount of times.

Comment: `HAVING MIN(COUNT(x)) = COUNT(x)`

Comment: @Aganju - I get a "group function is nested to deeply" error when I try that.

Comment: Don't use `natural join`!  It doesn't even use properly declared foreign key relationships . . . and it can introduce very hard-to-debug errors.

Comment: Unrelated, but: are you aware that `COUNT('x')` has no performance (or other) advantages over `count(*)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. This is also a good example of why we should use WITH (subquery factoring) instead of an inline view. creating a song_count subquery factoring with year, song_code and count.

Also, I would explicitly define the joins for clarity

```
WITH song_count as 
    SELECT extract(year from date) AS song_year, song_code, count(*) as play_count
    FROM singles NATURAL JOIN plays
    group by extract(year from date),song_code
select * from song_count
where
 (song_year,play_count) in (select song_year,min(play_count) from song_count group by song_year)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! I got it working perfectly. You're missing a "from" in your select * song_count though, it took me a second to catch, but after that everything worked fine.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

-- *You can prefer using analytic functions such as `dense_rank()` rather than joins or in-subqueries.*

```
with songs( id, year, play_id ) as
(
 select 1, 2018, 1 from dual union all    
 select 2, 2018, 1 from dual union all    
 select 3, 2018, 1 from dual union all
 select 3, 2018, 2 from dual union all
 select 1, 2017, 1 from dual union all 
 select 2, 2017, 1 from dual union all
 select 2, 2017, 2 from dual
)
select id, year, play_cnt
from
  (select s.*, dense_rank() over (partition by year order by play_cnt) dr
   from 
      (select id, year, count(play_id) as play_cnt
       from songs s
       group by id, year
      ) s
  )
where dr = 1;

        ID       YEAR   PLAY_CNT
---------- ---------- ----------
         1       2017          1
         2       2018          1
         1       2018          1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with row_number():

```
SELECT * 
FROM music 
NATURAL JOIN 
 (select yr, song_code, play_count
 from 
   (SELECT extract(year from date) AS yr, song_code, COUNT('x') play_count, row_number() over (partition by  extract(year from date), song_code order by COUNT('x')) rn
    FROM singles NATURAL JOIN plays 
    GROUP BY extract(year from date), song_code
   )
   where rn = 1;
```

Comment: I believe this would work when there is only one minimum, but there can be multiple minimum values in my case. i.e. several songs could only have one play a year, and I'd like the song_code for each of them.